# Returning a dynamically typed dict

Tags: python, python-typing

Given:

```py
@dataclass
class Datum(abc.ABC, Generic[T]):
    name: str # <- this could be become a Literal
    calculate: CalculateFn[T]
```

and the function

```
async def resolve(datum: Datum[T], ctx: GraphContext) -> T:
```

is there any way to make a function `resolve_many` …

```py
async def resolve_many(properties: list[Datum], ctx: GraphContext):
    ...
```

that returns a typeddict or whatever that has `name` as key and `T` as value with correct type for each key ?

Comment: No, definitely not I'm afraid. You can return a `dict[str, T]` or the likes, by there's no way for static type analysis to meaningfully use `TypedDict` whose keys are determined by the _runtime_ elements of some list. `TypeDict` is only appropriate when the keys are statically known, not when they can take on any values at runtime.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "this could be become a Literal" in your most recent edit? If that's true, then you could create a `TypeDict` with one key for every value passed to `Literal`. E.g. `Literal['a', 'b']` could become `class Foo(TypedDict): a: T;  b: T`, though `T` would have to be fixed since `TypedDict`s can't inherit from `Generic` IIRC